# How to open a file in multiple programs as my 'default program'

Tags: windows

So I've got a lot of manual HTML checking to do, most of which is just a quick glance at the code and then make sure the page displays correctly.

My thought is that it would be much easier to do this if I could set multiple programs to open when I double click on a .htm file. By this I mean open the file in the programs I specify all at once without multiple "right-click > open with > the program" actions.

So really I'd like for it to open in my HTML editor, Chrome, and Firefox all at once and then I can just glance at them all and move about my business. I figure I'll still have to close all of them manually but at least I can do that every once in a while not EVERY time.

Any ideas? I was thinking about a simple man-in-the middle app to open all of the programs, but that seems like it would be a rather large solution to a small issue, is there a simple (and fairly quick-to-execute) way of doing this in a windows-based fashion, or should I just try and slim down this proposed app as much as possible and maybe it won't be too slow to open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking about a simple man-in-the middle app to open all of the programs

That is exactly what you need.  And then you can add that app to the "Open With" menu of the file extension(s) you want to process.

> that seems like it would be a rather large solution to a small issue

Not really.  It would actually be a very small app to implement.  All you need is a configuration to specify the target apps, then receive the selected filename(s) as command-line parameters and pass them in a loop to the other apps using `ShellExecute/Ex()` or `CreateProcess()`as needed.  Not much to it.

> is there a simple (and fairly quick-to-execute) way of doing this in a windows-based fashion

Not really.  You have to create your own app for it, and then register it so you can invoke it when needed.

> should I just try and slim down this proposed app as much as possible and maybe it won't be too slow to open?

It won't be slow at all, unless you make it slow.  If you really want to cut down overhead, you could even implement it as a simple `.bat` script that uses the `start` command to launch the files, instead of compiling an actual executable.

Comment: Perfect, I love it. For now I'm gonna leave it as a batch file, but I might make a managing program later so I can do this for more than one thing. Basically I just use start 3 times with the parameter %~1. I'll let you know if I come up with an app for it that will create these batch files for a user, but for now, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you would create something called a [Shortcut Menu Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx). Beware, as that involves messing with the registry.